# Button Disabled/enabled on check-box state with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a reusable directive and using it in two different forms but unable to able/disable the button in form which changes according to the check-box state in directive. I want disable the button until checkbox is not checked and disable it whenever check-box get unchecked.

My [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1wg0c24f/25/)

### HTML

```
<div ng-app='demo'>
  <form name="verification" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
    <terms-conditions conditions="conditions"></terms-conditions>
    <br>
    <button class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked" >Submit</button>
    <hr>
  </form>

  <form name="bankinfo" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
    <terms-conditions conditions="conditions"></terms-conditions>
      <br>
      <button class="btn-primary">Submit</button>
      <hr>
  </form>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive("termsConditions",function(){
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        conditions:'='

    },
    template:
    "<div class='terms row'><span class='col-md-12'>{{conditions}}</span></div><br><input type='checkbox'><span>Yes, I agree to the terms and condtions</span>"
}

});
demo.controller("myCtrl1",function($scope){
    $scope.conditions= " Payment terms" ;

})
demo.controller("myCtrl2",function($scope){
 $scope.conditions= "Bank Terms" ;

});
```

### CSS

```
span {
  font-weight:bold;
}
.terms{font-weight: normal;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #666666;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, you need to pass `checked` attribute value as the 2 way binding property and use ng-disabled.

```
  <terms-conditions conditions="conditions" checked="checked"></terms-conditions>   <br>
  <button class="btn-primary" ng-disabled="!checked" >Submit</button>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fpybzp4/)**

Comment: Thanks very much  :) unable to vote up as need minimum 15 reputation.
:)  I am pretty new to angular. I have seen lot of online videos and tried reading some books too. And now trying Hands on Practice.I think more you do it... more you get it .

Comment: @MandeepSinghThakur No problem. If this satisfies you you could mark as answer. You will get there! :) All the best with your learning..